# How to optimizing a function that takes two different forms in two different regions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, stochastic-calculus

[image]

a,b,and P are non-negative constants. And $\theta$ is a random variable with distribution function $F(\theta)$ and density function $f(\theta)$. Denote $H(\theta)= {F(\theta)\over f(\theta)}$. No constraints.
My method is letting the first-order derivative equals to zero, and get the optimal $z(\theta)$, but there is a problem that ${(P-z(\theta))}^+$ is a non-differentiable function, so can't use first-order derivative.

Comment: What is the meaning of the random variable $\frac{f(\theta)}{F(\theta)}$?

Comment: Do you mean that this is a variation problem and you have to find the optimal function of $\theta$?

Comment: $H(\theta)$ means  the reciprocal of the failure rate of the distribution F at θ for any θ in its support. And yes, I want to find the optimal function of $\theta$, namely,$x(\theta)$.

Comment: sorry,not $x(\theta)$, is $z(\theta)$

Comment: This is a tough one then .... :(

Comment: How about rewrite the objective function into the integral form, and try to get the monotonicity of $z(\theta)$

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot help. I advise you to consult Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations